# Can we store 999.99 in a field DECIMAL(5,3) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am french student and I learn MySQL and SQL . In this time I learn different Numeric Types, and the teacher that said in DECIMAL type with parameter (5,3) it's possible to store numbers until 99.999, because 5-3 = 2 this which gives two numbers before comma .

Example :

```
DECIMAL(5,3);
```

we can store in this field 0.56, -48.123, 5.2, 78.458...

But the parameter 5 significate we can store a number with 5 numbers and 999.99 contains 5 numbers and this number have 3 numbers before comma...

I don't understand why my teacher said `DECIMAL(5,3)` can contains a number with 2 max numbers before comma ...

So I was wondering if anyone could tell me if I was right or wrong and if wrong why?

Thank you so much ! (Sorry if my english is bad)

Comment: No, you cannot store 999.99 in a `decimal(5, 3)` column.  You can in a `decimal(6, 3)` or `decimal(5, 2)`.  The "3" is *after* the decimal place, not before.  I think the documentation is quite clear (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html), so I'm voting to close.

Comment: In total `5` digits, where `3` are after the decimal point. I.e. 2 digits before, max 99.

Comment: It accepts `999.99` but save it as `99.999`. In other words, every value more than 99.999 (like 100) will be inserted as `99.999`.